# Use case statement for skip a filter in where affects the performance of the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, coding-style

I make this logic for all query that's requires a optional filter, so my question is this is a bad practice? Is affected the performance of execution?

Example:

```
SELECT 
    USR_NAME,
    USR_LAST_NAME
FROM 
    KTZ_USER
WHERE
    --- OPTIONAL FILTER ---
    (CASE 
        WHEN @V_USER_NAME IS NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN USR_NAME = @V_USER_NAME THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
            END 
     END) = 1
```

`@V_USER_NAME` is the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your where clause, but I would use this version:

```
SELECT USR_NAME, USR_LAST_NAME
FROM KTZ_USER
WHERE @V_USER_NAME IS NULL OR @V_USER_NAME = USR_NAME;
```

Generally `CASE` expressions are intended to be used for generating scalar values.  We can express your filter logic more directly without using them.

Comment: Thanks! So I have this in mind, maybe I m not right: using the query with the case statement when the query validate that the parameter is null, the following instruction is skip, so it optomizes the processing time as opposed to occupying the V_USER_NAME OR USR_NAME = V_USER_NAME , or this also has the same behavior? Check is null and skip OR condition

Comment: SQL Server is basically free to evaluate either side of the `OR` expression first.  The version I wrote above would probably be slightly more efficient than your original version using `CASE`.